# Remove duplicates in a foreach loop (but count them) - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have trouble removing duplicate IPs in a foreach loop (but count them) using Laravel 8. It returns the unique IPs but returns all rows count instead of each IP count.

**Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('visitors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('ip');
        $table->string('url');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->string('country');
        $table->string('browser')->nullable();
        $table->string('device')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function show()
{
    $data = Visitor::select('ip','url','city')->distinct('ip')->get();
    
    return view('admin.visitors.index', compact('data'));
}
```

**Blade**

```
 @foreach($data as $data)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $i++}}</td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $data->ip }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $data->count() }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $data->url }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $data->city }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $data->state }} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you want to use combination of count and group function:

```
$records = Visitor::selectRaw('ip, count(ip) as ipcount, url, city, state')->groupByRaw('ip, url, city, state')->get();
```

This will return count of unique combinations of ip + url + city + state.

```
 @foreach($records as $record)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $i++}}</td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $record->ip }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $record->ipcount }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $record->url }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $record->city }} </td>
       <td class="col-md-3">{{ $record->state }} </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ausista_z -  it worked exactly i wanted be with your code. Now along with unique ip's  i have got their duplicate count as well. Have a good one.

Comment: This is working fine, the only problem i am seeing now - cant fetch created _at with this query. When i added created_at in the above query then it fetches all the rows. How can we achieve fetch created_at at the same time?